# Load different property file based on input

Tags: web-services, spring, internationalization

I am developing an application that calls a java web service (using Jersey1.8). I need to invoke multiple property file based on input to the web service(User's language preference). If the user's language preference is Spanish, then I need to load the property file in Spanish. Is there any way to do this?.  Please help me. Thanks in advance.

- Note: The web service accepts Json object and returns Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use java resource bundle and setting proper name according the the language you wish to upload will solve your problem

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: sure see this it will help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html

Comment: Okay.Thanks for your time.But can we configure it using application-context.xml file?